# White screen and actionbar seen on app startup instead of black screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

As JadeMason said here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1440/74487:

"Black is the default plot color for Android, so this is the placeholder until the app completes it's layout operation"

I noticed most other apps do show black screen while starting up until their layout is ready to show.

However, my app instead shows white screen with the actionbar visible (but the menu items in the action bar are not visible; it is just the black/darkgrey bar and the app icon on the left side of it that are visible).

The background color of the main activity of my app is black. And the radical color transition between the complete white and complete black is so ugly and fatigues my eyes.

I'd like to have the default black screen during my app startup. How to achieve this?

More information on my app:

1. My app has `minSdkVersion 10` and `targetSdkVersion 20`.
2. My app theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (is it the appcompat that is
   causing this issue?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyril Mottier has a really great blog post about this topic [here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/).

Comment: It was an amazing post and it did more than help solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I agree - better than any answer I could have come up with ;). No problem